# SOAP request failure in R

Tags: r, xml, soap

I'm in trouble now.

I tried to use R for SOAP data exchange, but always get the server to respond as follows:

> Trying 210.242.163.56...
>
> Connected to 210.242.163.56 (210.242.163.56) port 80 (#0)
>
> POST /SendDigXml/ HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: 210.242.163.56
>
> Accept: text/xml
>
> Accept: multipart/*
>
> Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
>
> SOAPAction: http://210.242.163.56/SendDigXml/GetLastMod
>
> Content-Length: 397
>
> upload completely sent off: 397 out of 397 bytes
>
> < HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
>
> < Cache-Control: private
>
> < Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
>
> < Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>
> < X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>
> < X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>
> < Date: Tue, 01 Nov 2016 06:32:54 GMT
>
> < Content-Length: 441
>
> < Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> < Age: 0
>
> <
> Connection #0 to host 210.242.163.56 left intact

And faulcode and faultstring is :

```
<faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>The server could not recognize the value of the HTTP header SOAPAction: http://210.242.163.56/SendDigXml/GetLastMod/.</faultstring>
```

I'm using the curlPerform function in the RCurl Package, with the following code:

```
library(RCurl)
id ="iamuser"
pw ="letmepass"

headerFields =
 c(Accept = "text/xml",
Accept = "multipart/*",
'Content-Type' = "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
SOAPAction = "http://210.242.163.56/SendDigXml/GetLastMod")

body = sprintf('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<GetLastMod xmlns="http://210.242.163.56/SendDigXml/">
<user_id>%s</user_id>
<password>%s</password>
<county_code>%s</county_code>
<data_type>%s</data_type>
</GetLastMod>
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>',id,pw,"Y","1") 

reader = basicTextGatherer()

getupdate<-curlPerform(url = "http://210.242.163.56/SendDigXml/",
                   httpheader = headerFields,
                   postfields = body,
                   writefunction = reader$update,
                   verbose = TRUE)
```

SOAPAction value format is in accordance with the provisions of the template, and also tried several other representation, but the results are the same. I do not know what else I can try. Can someone help me?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

OK,I find out what's wrong.

SOAPAction should be `"http://tempuri.org/GetLastMod"` ,not `"http://210.242.163.56/SendDigXml/GetLastMod"`.

and `<GetLastMod xmlns="http://210.242.163.56/SendDigXml/">` should be `<GetLastMod xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">`

Just the same with sample code on the http://210.242.163.56/SendDigXml .

I think this is a mistake that any trained programmer will not make it.but I am not trained programer...I will keep this question instead to delete it. I hope it can help someone like me.